# Jquery Selectbox plugin onchange and remember

Tags: jquery, onchange, drop-down-menu

I'm using this plugin to style my selectboxes
http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin/

My first problem is that I have another piece of javascript that uses the onchange showDiv(this.value) to show a hidden div associated with the given value selected. It no longer works. I assume because this plugin is rewriting the select box options with jquery and not using the default option values. How do I get it to recognize those values and work with that onchange so my existing script will work again?

My second problem is that when refreshing the page, selected options reset. I would like it to remember what was selected before the refresh. Any idea how to incorporate that?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the onchange event in this plugin and it is working fine for me.. I have tried this in firebug and it is fine. I have used the below code:

```
function showDiv(val) {
  alert(val);
}
```

and its okay for me.